# Rotate a shape by 90 degrees

Tags: java, graphics

I trying to rotate a shape by 90 degrees  .

my shape is held by a class which has few points of (x,y) and lines of (point1,point2) which all the lines together component the shape.

Actually in order to rotate a shape by 90 (or any other angle) degrees it should transform the points of the shape by to follow formula  -

```
(x,y) -> (  x*cos(90)+y*sin(90) , -x*sin(90)+y*cos(90)  )
```

so to achieve the above I tried the follow (it operated on each point which is component of the shape ) -

```
float x, y;
// get the current point location ...
x = currentPoint.x;
y = currentPoint.y; 
// create the cos , sin
float cosA = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90));
float sinA = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90));
currentPoint.x = (int) (x * cosA + y * sinA);
currentPoint.y = (int) (-x * sinA + y * cosA);
```

but it gives very weird result when I draw the shape after this rotation  .

Can you detect something wrong in this implementation  ?

Comment: Are you using any Control or using Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extends JPanel and use your class with implementing this method. Here is the code to rotate the JPanel control

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int w2 = getWidth() / 2;
    int h2 = getHeight() / 2;
    g2d.rotate(-Math.PI / 2, w2, h2);
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Now use this custom class instead of JPanel

Comment: Why the `/2` in `w2` and `h2`  ?

Comment: Problems should not always be answered in some library use. I came here to find the solution to implement the function of rotation by myself for learning purposes. Many other will also came for same type of problem.